# Visual Studio Code: Unexpected error at running Selection/Line in python terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Not sure anyone faced the same error before. When I choose to run the selection/line in python terminal at line:

```
a = 5
```

The terminal returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Which indicates that what is actually submitted is `a`, instead of the full command. The issue is gone when the space is removed, i.e. `a=5`. Same thing goes for both Python 2 and 3. Feel something goes wrong with the keybinding setting.

---

Find a clue that, if there is a parenthesis, then the full line will be submitted. For example

```
a = (5)
```

works well to define a as 5.

Comment: Are you sure the Python extension for VS Code is still installed? The menu options are still there in the latest release of the extension.

Comment: Yes, the extension is still there. I find that when I changed the python interpreter back to the local one from anaconda, the issue gets resolved. Guess something goes wrong with the anaconda environment? Many thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: We did try using `conda run` in our latest release which broke some scenarios, including sending code to the REPL, but we reverted back in a point release so I would give it another try.

Comment: I see. Thank you Brett for the clue! Will definitely try it again!